# How to close stream on app shutdown when created in main?

Tags: flutter

I have a custom http client that intercepts responses to provide service unavailable events via a stream:

```
class MyHttpClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final String apiBase;

  MyHttpClient({required this.apiBase});

  final _controller = StreamController<ServiceUnavailableEvent>.broadcast();

  Stream<ServiceUnavailableEvent> get stream => _controller.stream;


  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) async {
    final response = await request.send();
    if (request.url.toString().startsWith(apiBase) &&
        response.statusCode == HttpStatus.serviceUnavailable) {
      _controller.sink.add(ServiceUnavailableEvent(isAvailable: false));
    } else {
      _controller.sink.add(ServiceUnavailableEvent(isAvailable: true));
    }
    return response;
  }

  Future<void> close() async {
    await _controller.close();
  }
}
```

The client is instanciated once in the `main` flutter function:

```
void main() {
  final client = MyHttpClient(apiBase: apiBase)
  runApp(MyApp(client: client));
}
```

Everything works fine and I added the `close` method on the custom http client that closes the stream. But when/how can I call this `close` method ?

I thought about [`AppLifeCycleEvent`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html) but all state seem to be the wrong place, because I only want to close the client when the app really shuts down (i.e. if the user re-opens/resumes the app a new client must be created in order to recreate the subscription).

Answer (score 0):

how do you know it is still open when app shutdown. i think platform(ios/android) close it.